# UDF function for a double datatype in PySpark

Tags: function, apache-spark, pyspark, double, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a column using UDF function in PySpark.

The code I tried looks like this:

```py
# The function checks year and adds a multiplied value_column to the final column

def new_column(row, year):
    if year == "2020":
        return row * 0.856 
    elif year == "2019": 
        return row * 0.8566
    else:
        return row

final_udf = F.udf(lambda z: new_column(z), Double()) #How do I get - Double datatype here 
res = res.withColumn("final_value", final_udf(F.col('value_column'), F.col('year')))
```

How can I write Double() in `final_udf`?
I see that for string we can use `StringType()`. But what can I do to return double type in the "final_value" column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T
res = spark.createDataFrame([(1.0, '2020',), (1.0, '2019',), (1.0, '2018',)], ['value_column', 'year'])
```

*`udf` is very inefficient when dealing with big data.*

You should first try to do it in **native Spark:**

```py
res = res.withColumn(
    'final_value',
    F.when(F.col('year') == "2020", F.col('value_column') * 0.856)
     .when(F.col('year') == "2019", F.col('value_column') * 0.8566)
     .otherwise(F.col('value_column'))
)
res.show()
# +------------+----+-----------+
# |value_column|year|final_value|
# +------------+----+-----------+
# |         1.0|2020|      0.856|
# |         1.0|2019|     0.8566|
# |         1.0|2018|        1.0|
# +------------+----+-----------+
```

If it's impossible in native Spark, turn to **`pandas_udf`**:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T
import pandas as pd

@F.pandas_udf(T.DoubleType())
def new_column(row: pd.Series, year: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    if year == "2020":
        return row * 0.856 
    elif year == "2019": 
        return row * 0.8566
    else:
        return row

res = res.withColumn("final_value", final_udf('value_column', 'year'))

res.show()
# +------------+----+-----------+
# |value_column|year|final_value|
# +------------+----+-----------+
# |         1.0|2020|      0.856|
# |         1.0|2019|     0.8566|
# |         1.0|2018|        1.0|
# +------------+----+-----------+
```

Only as a last resort you should go for `udf`:

```py
@F.udf(T.DoubleType())
def new_column(row, year):
    if year == "2020":
        return row * 0.856 
    elif year == "2019": 
        return row * 0.8566
    else:
        return row

res = res.withColumn("final_value", new_column('value_column', 'year'))

res.show()
# +------------+----+-----------+
# |value_column|year|final_value|
# +------------+----+-----------+
# |         1.0|2020|      0.856|
# |         1.0|2019|     0.8566|
# |         1.0|2018|        1.0|
# +------------+----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple string `"double"` or import pypspark's [DoubleType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType.html)

```
# like this
final_udf = F.udf(lambda z: new_column(z), "double")

# or this
import pyspark.sql.types as T
final_udf = F.udf(lambda z: new_column(z), T.DoubleType())
```